# dijit BorderContainer auto-grow

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

Is there a way to have a `dijit.layout.BorderContainer` auto-grow in height? I've tried setting `min-height: 200px; height: auto;`, but it won't scale.

I've tried looking at the [API](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dijit.layout.BorderContainer), but that thing is a mess... So any help would be appreciated (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [resize() method](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dijit.layout.BorderContainer.resize) to change its size dynamically.

> The outer size must be specified on the BorderContainer node

You need to specify width/height on the BorderContainer itself, in pixels.  You can't use auto, and min-height isn't supported AFAIK.  You can, however, use widget attributes minSize and maxSize to set boundaries on the splitters within the container.

Comment: Ah, so I can't just tell it to auto-expand to fit the entire content? I will have to calculate the height of the content myself and set it?

Comment: there is an exception... you may specify that BorderContainer should [take over the entire window](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html#setting-sizes) at 100% of the BODY tag, but you must declare the CSS exactly as specified in the docs, where the body must have an explicit size setting as well.